# C#. POP3 Client using WebClient or HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, pop3

I try to receive messages from mailbox. I found how to do this using tcp client:

```
static void Receive()
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient ("mail.isp.com ", 110))
    using (NetworkStream n = client.GetStream())
    {
        ReadLine (n);                             // Read the welcome message.
        SendCommand (n, "USER username");
        SendCommand (n, "PASS password");
        SendCommand (n, "LIST");                  // Retrieve message IDs
        List<int> messageIDs = new List<int>();
        while (true)
        {
            string line = ReadLine (n);             // e.g.  "1 1876"
            if (line == ".") break;
            messageIDs.Add (int.Parse (line.Split (' ')[0] ));   // Message ID
        }

        foreach (int id in messageIDs)         // Retrieve each message.
        {
            SendCommand (n, "RETR " + id);
            string randomFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".eml";
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText (randomFile))
            while (true)
            {
                string line = ReadLine (n);      // Read next line of message.
                if (line == ".") break;          // Single dot = end of message.
                if (line == "..") line = ".";    // "Escape out" double dot.
                writer.WriteLine (line);         // Write to output file.
            }
            SendCommand (n, "DELE " + id);       // Delete message off server.
        }
        SendCommand (n, "QUIT");
    }
}
```

How can I receive mail using web request?
I need to do this using http client.
Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to do this with WebClient, but you do realize that HTTP Client is for HTTP/S and not POP3, correct?

Comment: WebClient abstracts ftp and http protocols; httpclient, http.  Pop3 is neither of those protocols.

Comment: @Jordan McGuigan, yes. I don't now how to receive messages from mail using WebClient

Comment: @Peter Ritchie, I understand. I want to implement simple operations like read mail, delete messages from gmail (for example) using WebClient class or HttpClient class

Comment: @user3443227 You can't, POP3 is *not HTTP-based*  Why not use a library like http://readypop.com/